# can someone please tell is there any java built in package for Circular Queue?

Tags: java, queue, circular-queue

I want to know that is there any java built-in package for a circular queue
and if it exists then what is the constructor to use it?

Comment: [First google hit…](https://www.javainuse.com/java/circular_java) I think you have to implement one yourself or use an existing library.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803724/circular-linkedlist-in-java

Comment: i can implement it but i want to know if there is any library exist in java or not?

Comment: No there isn't. Have you tried googling it though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Class CircularFifoBuffer` from `apache` to build a buffer with a fixed size that replaces its oldest element if full.

The constructor would look like this:

```
Buffer circularQueue = new CircularFifoBuffer(size);
```

From de official documentation:

> public class CircularFifoBuffer
>   extends BoundedFifoBuffer
>
> CircularFifoBuffer is a first in first out buffer with a fixed size that replaces its oldest element if full.
>   The removal order of a CircularFifoBuffer is based on the insertion order; elements are removed in the same order in which they were added. The iteration order is the same as the removal order.
>
> The add(Object), BoundedFifoBuffer.remove() and BoundedFifoBuffer.get() operations all perform in constant time. All other operations perform in linear time or worse.
>
> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. The following can be used to provide synchronized access to your CircularFifoBuffer:

Check the documentation: [public class CircularFifoBuffer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html)

Comment: It isn't really build it if it is a third party apache library now is it? But yeah, this exists I guess.

Comment: Thank you @Paplusc