# how to set next of last element of linked list to first element in LinkedList data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to use `java.util.LinkedList` to get a linked list and change it somehow to a circular linked list.

Like is it possible to set next of the last element to first (as it can be done in a self-made linked list)?

If not then please suggest me another way to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular LinkedList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803724/circular-linkedlist-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't generate a circular `LinkedList`. A circular `LinkedList` would not be able to implement its own API. How would `LinkedList.add` work, for example, if the list had no end?

You identified the solution: implement your own linked list.

Comment: I thought about that, and `forEach`. In theory you could define those as returning/visiting each node only once. However, such a definition would be at odds with the notion of a circular list. If `forEach` terminates then the list has an end, which means it isn't really circular.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use LinkedList, but you can implement your own solution.
For example you can just create class containing list and declare you own API for use it. E.g.

```
public static class CircularList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public void add(T num) {
        list.add(num);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            int idx = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }

                if (idx + 1 < list.size()) {
                    return list.get(++idx);
                }

                idx = 0;
                return list.get(0);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is a simple implementation of a circular list.

Comment: Might also want to limit the size (a typical use of circular lists). That adds a little complexity because you have to monitor `size` and overwrite from the front if the list is full.